# How to list Branches using LibGit2 C++?

Tags: c++, git, qt, libgit2

I am trying to create a simple User Interface using Qt, c++ and LibGit2 which displays git branches.

I've done research but cant seem to find anything that explains the process of doing this.

I am still new to C++ and git so I'm sorry in advance if you think this is a stupid question. I'm just trying to learn something new.

Answer (score 4):

See the `git_branch_iterator` functions. For example:

```
git_branch_iterator *it;
if (!git_branch_iterator_new(&it, repo, GIT_BRANCH_ALL)) {
  git_reference *ref;
  git_branch_t type;
  while (!git_branch_next(&ref, &type, it)) {
    // Do something with 'ref' and 'type'.
    git_reference_free(ref);
  }
  git_branch_iterator_free(it);
}
```